# Is "his wife" a pronoun in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns, subjects, objects

In this sentence, I know "them" is a pronoun but I'm not sure if "his wife" is a pronoun or not?

Rand loves sports cars, and **his wife** loves **them** too

Comment: It is a Subject.

Comment: No, it's a noun phrase. It has the noun "wife" as head, and the genitive personal pronoun "his" as determiner.

Comment: "Them" is also a noun phrase, with the pronoun "them" as head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"His wife" is a noun phrase here. "them", which you also made bold, is a pronoun.

Comment: "Them" is also an NP consisting of just the pronoun "them".

Comment: @BillJ depends on the framework I guess